# Symbols in header files C/C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, header-files

How to find what symbols are being referenced in a header-file by my source files?
I want to find out programmatically.

Comment: What do you mean by "programmatically"?

Comment: Symbols after or before name mangling?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a cross-reference tool.

Comment: maybe a doc tool could provide stub documentation based on the headers... like doxygen

Comment: You won't be able to find the macro generated symbols unless you do the cross reference from the preprocessed output.

Comment: I have legacy header files, from which I am using some declarations and macros. I want to find them and remove the rest of the stuff from it.
I am not sure if looking into the final elf object will help in doing that. any idea ??

Comment: @maniksheeri: Remove the header and let the compiler complain about what is really needed.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas I am aware of this method. It's just too laborious. So wanted to know if there is a better alternative.

Comment: Some compilers can generate a *cross reference* report about symbols and where they are used.  If the compiler can't do it, maybe the linker can.

Answer (score 4):

The brute force method:

1. In your source file, comment out the inclusion of a header file.
2. Recompile the source file.

The compiler should emit a list of undefined symbols.

You may need to apply recursively if your header file includes other files.

**Edit 1: Map files**
Your compiler may be able to generate a **cross reference** listing of symbols and where they are used.  This is specific to each compiler.  Consult your compiler's documentation.

Also check the linker's documentation as well.

The compiler can generate a **map** file which shows symbols, their values and their locations.  This may show where symobls are used, but most likely not in header files.

Comment: Smart move there