# How can we find what symbols are being looked for by linker?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, clang, nm

I'm getting a strange error, my libs have the definition of symbol it should be looking for, but still throws error "Unreferenced symbol for arm64 architecture"

now I tried `lipo -info libQt5Core.a` which gave me "Architectures in the fat file: libQt5Core.a are: x86_64 arm64" to make sure I have libs for correct architecture.

Is there any cmake command (probably enabling linker flag, I'm using clang toolchain for IOS) which gives out a list of symbols linker is trying to find in lib files?

what I'm asking for is essentially how to get a Map file (as mentioned in this [Symbols in header files C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064811/symbols-in-header-files-c-c)) generated via cmake for clang toolchain for IOS.

I'm not asking to see what symbols are available in my lib as I can see that info with `nm libQt5Core.a`

I've seen these ones before asking

1. [How to generate Map file using cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244445/how-to-generate-map-file-using-cmake)
2. [Generate .map file with clang and lld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60990561/generate-map-file-with-clang-and-lld)

Comment: Are the libraries listed in the correct order on the linker command line? Given your Qt library contains x86_64 and arm is it compiled for macos rather than ios?

Comment: I'm providing it Qt path for IOS in cmake as `set(Qt5_DIR "/Users/inkfil/Qt/5.12.11/ios/lib/cmake/Qt5")` so this should be qt for ios

and

regarding the order off linking, I'm not sure, but this is my order in cmake "Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets Qt5::OpenGL Qt5::Multimedia Qt5::Network Qt5::Sql Qt5::Quick Qt5::QuickWidgets Qt5::Svg Qt5::WebView"

Comment: Have you checked that the directory you've set is actually the one being linked with?